# Regularly automated re-scheduling of UILocalNotification through background mode?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, background-process, uilocalnotification

It's known that UILocalNotification can be only scheduled up to 64. Would it be possible to create an app that runs in background mode that regularly creates new schedules as older ones expire?

For example, you could store the schedule dates in core data and the app regularly checks to see how many have them have expired, and then reschedule more based on that information.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to keep your app alive in the background indefinitely, or to have it wake up on a schedule to make the check.  If you can live with the fact that all 64 notifications might be shown before the app is run again and has a chance to schedule more, then you can do what you want.

That said, you do know that a UILocalNotification can repeat on its own, right?  (See repeatCalendar/repeatInterval properties).
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW3

Comment: Thank you. Also I am trying to customize each notification based on when it gets triggered and as far as I know this is the only way. Do you know of a way to customize the message without creating separate notifications?